# Why is the image not showing in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, css

I have an image on this [page](http://173.201.163.213/idea_people_charlotte_what_we_do.html) in the blue bar area. It shows up fine in FF, Safari, IE8 & Chrome, but it does not show up in IE7.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="featuredImage">
  <img src="images/website_design_charlotte.jpg" width="960" height="159" alt="" />
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#featuredImage   { position: absolute; z-index: 9; top: 129px; left: 0; }
#featuredImage img   { width: 986px; height: 159px; position: relative; z-index: 10; }
```

Would appreciate some help getting this to show up properly in IE7.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few lines down in your HTML you have this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

... which means all the other browsers are using `Water.css` for the stylesheet, but IE is using `style-ie.css`.  Since you say it *is* working for IE8, the problem may be in your code that determines the browser version.

Comment: I have corrected the reference to the IE-specific style sheets, but the image still remains hidden.

Comment: Change the `z-index` property, perhaps? Using "9" and "10" for the z-indexes seems pretty magic-numbery. Perhaps IE7 has a different default layering of your page.

Comment: set it to 100 and 200 respectively without any different results.

Comment: That's the end of my ideas. If you could reduce this to a simple HTML page (with CSS) that demonstrates the problem (without any external links), it would be easy for somebody to figure out and fix.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue while working with image material from a client. I received about 10 images, of which all worked fine but two, and I could not figure out why IE was behaving like that (didn't show a 404 or anything).

Turns out the two misbehaving images were saved with CMYK colors, where the others were RGB. Converted them in Photoshop, bang, works.

So if anyone runs into this issue, you might just try that. Idiot clients, idiot IE.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem by replacing an JPG image with PNG format